# Why cant I get a form pre-filled with my objects information?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, react-native, react-router

Hi I have a react frontend and rails backend.Not sure where the prob is but im trying to get an update done for  reservations object.When I click edit it renders me to the edited form  and I want it to be prefilled with the current values..Im really not sure whether im doing something wrong with my routes or the backend or the useEffect.Pls check out my code ....
App.js
This is where I defined my `const[reservations,setReservations]=useState([]);` and passed it down as props and also all my routes are defined here.

```
import './App.css';

import { useEffect,useState } from 'react';
import About from './components/About'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Restaurants from './components/Restaurants';
import Loggin from './components/Loggin';
import RestaurantInfo from './components/RestaurantInfo';
import MyReservations from './components/MyReservations';
import { Route,Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Blogs from './components/Blogs';
import EditForm from './components/EditForm';
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const[reservations,setReservations]=useState([]);

 
 
 
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Nyc";
  }, []);

 
 
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // auto-login
    fetch("/me", { credentials: "same-origin" }).then((r) => {
      if (r.ok) {
        r.json().then((user) => setUser(user));
      }
    });
  }, [setUser]);


  if (!user) return <Loggin error={'please login'} onLogin={setUser} />;
  return (
    <div className="App">
   <Navbar user={user} setUser={setUser} />
   <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/blogs" element={<Blogs />} />
    <Route exact path="/reservations/:id/update" element={<EditForm reservations={reservations} setReservations={setReservations} />}/>
  
    <Route exact path="/myreservations" element={<MyReservations user={user} reservations={reservations} setReservations={setReservations} />} />

   <Route exact path="/restaurants/:id" element= {<RestaurantInfo user={user} />}  />

      <Route exact path="/restaurants" element={<Restaurants />} />

     <Route exact path="/about" element={<About user={user} />} />

   </Routes>
   
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

MyReservations

```
import {useEffect } from "react";
import ReservationCard from "./ReservationCard";

function MyReservations({user,reservations,setReservations}){
   
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch("/reservations")
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(reservationData=>{
          setReservations(reservationData)
        })
      },[])

      
      function handleUpdateReservation(updatedReservation) {
        const updatedReservations = reservations.map((reservation) =>{
        return reservation.id === updatedReservation.id ? updatedReservation : reservation;
         } );
        setReservations(updatedReservations);
      }
     


     
    return(
        <>
       
        {reservations.map((reservation)=>(
        <ReservationCard key={reservation.id} reservation={reservation}  handleUpdateReservation={handleUpdateReservation} />
        
       ))

       }
        </>
    )
}
export default MyReservations;
```

Edit.Reservation

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

function EditForm({reservations,setReservations}){
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch("/reservations/${reservation.id}")
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(reservationData=>{
          setReservations(reservationData)
        })
      },[])

    
    return(
        <>
        <h1>Edit form</h1>
         <form >
        <div >
        <label htmlFor="name"  >Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" defaultValue={reservations.name}  placeholder="name" />
       </div>
       <div >
        <label htmlFor="date"  >Date</label>
         <input type="date" name="date"  defaultValue={reservations.date} placeholder="date" />
       </div>
       <div >
        <label htmlFor="time"  >Time</label>
         <input type="time" name="time" defaultValue={reservations.time}  placeholder="time" />
       </div>
       <div >
        <label htmlFor="num"  >Num</label>
         <input type="number" name="num"  defaultValue={reservations.num}  placeholder="num" />
       </div>
       <div >
        <label htmlFor="date"  >Contact</label>
         <input type="tel" name="contact" defaultValue={reservations.contact} placeholder="contact" />
       </div>
       <div >
        <label htmlFor="occasion"  >Occasion</label>
         <input type="text" name="occasion" defaultValue={reservations.occasion}  placeholder="occasion" />
       </div>
       <button type="submit">Update Reservation</button>

       </form>
        </>
    )
}
export default EditForm;
```

Just for some extra info.....
Here is my resservation form

```
import { useState} from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function ReservationForm({user}){
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const params = useParams();

    const[reservationData,setReservationData]=useState({
        name:"",
        date:"",
        time:"",
        num:"",
        contact:"",
        occasion:"",
    });
    function handleReservationChange(event){
        setReservationData({
            ...reservationData,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        })
    }
    function handleReservationSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const newReservation={
            ...reservationData,
            restaurant_id: params.id,
            user_id: user.id,
        };

        fetch(`/reservations`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newReservation),
          })
            .then((r) => r.json())
            .then(
                setReservationData({
                name:"",
                date:"",
                time:"",
                num:"",
                contact:"",
                occasion:"",
              })
            );
          navigate("/myreservations");
        }

    
    return(
        <>
       <h1>Reservation</h1> 
       <form onSubmit={handleReservationSubmit}>
        <div >
        <label htmlFor="name"  >Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" value={reservationData.name} onChange={handleReservationChange} placeholder="name" />
       </div>
       <div >
        <label htmlFor="date"  >Date</label>
         <input type="date" name="date" value={reservationData.date} onChange={handleReservationChange} placeholder="date" />
       </div>
       <div >
        <label htmlFor="time"  >Time</label>
         <input type="time" name="time" value={reservationData.time} onChange={handleReservationChange} placeholder="time" />
       </div>
       <div >
        <label htmlFor="num"  >Num</label>
         <input type="number" name="num" value={reservationData.num} onChange={handleReservationChange} placeholder="num" />
       </div>
       <div >
        <label htmlFor="date"  >Contact</label>
         <input type="tel" name="contact" value={reservationData.contact} onChange={handleReservationChange} placeholder="contact" />
       </div>
       <div >
        <label htmlFor="occasion"  >Occasion</label>
         <input type="text" name="occasion" value={reservationData.occasion} onChange={handleReservationChange} placeholder="occasion" />
       </div>
       <button type="submit">Reserve</button>

       </form>

        </>
    )
}
export default ReservationForm;
```

And rails backend

```
config routes.rb 
resources :reservations,only: [:index,:create,:update,:destroy]
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        reservations = @current_user.reservations
         render json: reservations
      end

    def create
        reservation=Reservation.create!(reservation_params)
        render json: reservation,status: :created


    end

    def update
        reservation = Reservation.find_by(id: params[:id])
        review.update!(reservation_params)
        render json: reservation,status: :ok

    end
  

    def destroy
   
        reservation = Reservation.find_by(id:params[:id])
        if reservation
          reservation.destroy
          head :no_content

        else
            render json: {error: "Reservation Not Found ."}, status: :not_found
        end
    end



    private
    
    def reservation_params
        params.permit(:name, :date, :time, :num, :contact, :occasion,:user_id,:restaurant_id)

    end
   
end
```

Comment: What is the `GET` request in `EditForm` supposed to fetch? It appears its purpose is to fetch a *specific* reservation, but then it overwrites the `reservations` state array. Are you sure you don't just need to access the `id` route path param and edit the reservation object in the `reservations` array passed in props? Or do you really need to make a separate fetch for data you (*presumably*) already have?

Answer (score 1):

The `EditForm` should look like this:

- get `id` from URL
- fetch reservation by `id` and set `reservationData`
- while `reservationData` is undefined return "Loading..."
- `handleReservationSubmit` should be similar to `ReservationForm`

```
function EditForm({ reservations, setReservations }) {
  const [reservationData, setReservationData] = useState();
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/reservations/${id}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((reservationData) => {
        setReservationData(reservationData);
      });
  }, [id]);

  function handleReservationChange(event) {
    setReservationData({
      ...reservationData,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  function handleReservationSubmit(event) {
    //
  }

  if (!reservationData) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Edit form</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleReservationSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={reservationData.name}
            onChange={handleReservationChange}
            placeholder="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="date">Date</label>
          <input
            type="date"
            name="date"
            value={reservationData.date}
            onChange={handleReservationChange}
            placeholder="date"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="time">Time</label>
          <input
            type="time"
            name="time"
            value={reservationData.time}
            onChange={handleReservationChange}
            placeholder="time"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="num">Num</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="num"
            value={reservationData.num}
            onChange={handleReservationChange}
            placeholder="num"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="date">Contact</label>
          <input
            type="tel"
            name="contact"
            value={reservationData.contact}
            onChange={handleReservationChange}
            placeholder="contact"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="occasion">Occasion</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="occasion"
            value={reservationData.occasion}
            onChange={handleReservationChange}
            placeholder="occasion"
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Update Reservation</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```